# Eroor StackOverFlow when trying to move a rigid body sphere using mouse right click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hei guys i have to make to make a rigid body sphere to move when i click right mouse click . 
**I got a big problem, program StackOverFlow and i don't know how to make it run fine.Maybe the problem is because I call recursive my method but I really don't have any other ideea **

There is what i did until now in my script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class Bundary
{
public float xMin, xMax, zMin, zMax;
}

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField]
[Range(1, 20)]
private float speed;

private Vector3 targetPosition;
private bool isMoving;

public Rigidbody rigidBody;
public Bundary bundary;

const int RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON = 1;

private void Start()
{
    targetPosition = transform.position;
    isMoving = false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets the travel position where we will travel
/// </summary>
void SetTargetPosition()
{
    Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    float point = 0f;

    if (plane.Raycast(ray, out point))
        targetPosition = ray.GetPoint(point);

    //set the ball to move
    isMoving = true;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.LookAt(targetPosition);  
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, 0.0f, Input.mousePosition.z); //how much we want to move
    rigidBody.velocity = movement * speed;   //because movement return a value bettwen (0,1) we want the ball move faster so multiply it with our speed
    rigidBody.position = new Vector3                                   
        (Mathf.Clamp(rigidBody.position.x, bundary.xMin, bundary.xMax),  //set x limits with Clamp method
        0.0f,                                                            //we don't want to move it on Y axex
        Mathf.Clamp(rigidBody.position.z, bundary.zMin, bundary.zMax));  //set y limits with Clamp method
    //if we are in the target position ,then stop moving !
    if (movement == targetPosition)
        isMoving = false;

    //if the player clicked  on the screen , found out where
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON))
        SetTargetPosition();

    //if we are still moving ,then move the player
    if (isMoving)
        FixedUpdate();

}
}
```

There is what my program should do in the final stage :http://prntscr.com/fqu98u

Comment: You forgot to mention the problem.

Comment: I got a big problem, program StackOverFlow and i don't know how to make it run fine.i wrote it ,read carefully

Comment: If you get an error should post the error. Also, tell us the line of code that is causing that error by double clicking on that error. Is this a top down or side view game?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fqua1i  look , there is my error, and also a wiew of game.

Comment: Read carefully? 1.There wasn't anything that described your problem in your question. 2.Editing it with bolded texts won't help either. 3.When you have error in your *next* question, please post the error to the question instead of a screenshot of it on the comment section. Good luck!

Comment: Man....i just want some help , i thought it is clear what was the problem when i wrote the description... I will consider you advice and post it more detailed . But I don;t have any ideea why it give me StackOverflow , it is sure because about my recursive call of Method , but i don;t have other ideea, that's why I post here...to recive some help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is two fold.

1. Inaccurate test for reaching destination
2. Your method shouldn't be recursive

You're getting a stack overflow error because your recursive code in **FixedUpdate** doesn't terminate properly when your object is moving. In your case **isMoving** is set to false once the target destination is reached.  Sadly your test for determining whether the point is reached is unlikely to occur due to floating point and you are testing for exact coordinates.  You are better off testing for reaching a point inside an imaginary sphere at the destination.

When writing recursive code you need to ensure that a condition exists that would terminate the call.  Yours doesn't. With each call, the current program counter is pushed onto the stack.  The stack is a limited resource where upon its exhaustion leads to a **stack overflow**.

Normally you would fix it but since FixedUpdate is called by Unity, you should just remove the recursive nature completely and let the method be called over time.